# How to Efficiently Read From a Pipe Stream when using IPC C#

Tags: c#, stream, ipc, named-pipes

I wrote the simplified version of my program below. Process A launches a child process (Process B). I use an anonymous pipe to write information about the progress of a method running on process B. Meanwhile I have a function in process A that continually reads from a stream to see if there is a new update coming in from the pipe. If there is, the form on process A is updated to reflect the progress. This works as expected, however I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this without having to continually check the stream to see if there are any new updates to the progress.

```
/////////////////
///Process A ////
/////////////////

public void LaunchProcessB()
{
    using (AnonymousPipeServerStream pipeServer = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.In,
            HandleInheritability.Inheritable))
    {
        var _Process = new Process();
        _Process.StartInfo.FileName = exeString;
        _Process.StartInfo.Arguments = pipeServer.GetClientHandleAsString()
        _Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        _Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        _Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        _Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        _Process.Start(); //launches process B

        pipeServer.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer))
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    string temp = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (temp == null) break;

                    int result;
                    if (Int32.TryParse(temp, out result))
                        ShowDocumentProgress(result);
                    else ShowProgress(temp);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //error occured when reading from stream.
            }
        }

        if (!_Process.Responding && !_Process.HasExited)
        {
            _Process.Kill();
            return;
        }

        _Process.WaitForExit(10000);
    }
}

private void ShowProgressPercent(int percentage)
{
    if (percentage > currentPercentage)
    {
        progressBar.Value = percentage;
    }
}

private void ShowProgress(string progressString)
{
    labelMessage.Text = progressString;
}


/////////////////
///Process B ////
/////////////////

private StreamWriter _progressWriter;
private PipeStream _progressPipe;

static int Main(string[] args)
{
    using (progressPipe = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.Out, args[0]))
    using (_progressWriter = new StreamWriter(_progressPipe))   
    {
        RunLongProcess()
    }
}

private void RunLongProcess() 
{
    //attaches events to PercentProgress and StageProgress methods.  
}

private void PercentProgress(int percentage)
{
    _progressWriter.WriteLine(percentage.ToString());
    _progressPipe.WaitForPipeDrain();
}

private void StageProgress(string stage) 
{
    _progressWriter.WriteLine(stage);
    _progressPipe.WaitForPipeDrain();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while condition is not necessary. Simply read until temp is null. That's the end signal of the stream.

Make this a `while(true)` loop.

I think you also need to add exception handling to catch the process terminating and severing the pipe. `!_Process.HasExited && pipeServer.IsConnected` is not enough because it might be true but immediately switch to false after the test.

I also would add a `WaitForExit` at the end to make sure the system is quiesced before you continue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I updated my code to reflect them. I still kept the pipeServer.IsConnected check in the while loop in order to avoid most exceptions from being thrown. I also added a check to ensure the process is still responsive.

Comment: That's broken in two ways: _Process.Responding is GUI-based, so probably not right. And even if you want those semantics, you might discard buffered data if the process becomes unresponsive. Secondly, even if pipeServer.IsConnected becomes false the streamreader might have data buffered that you will lose. `if (temp == null) continue;` this should be `... break;`. You will almost never see an exception here because most of the time the remote handle will be closed and you will receive null.

Comment: `_Process.Kill();
            return;` needs a WaitForExit es well because killing is not instantaneous. IOs might linger. Also, you should not kill the process just because it closed its pipe. It might still be doing things and shutting down. Maybe only kill, after WaitForExit has returned false?

Comment: I don't follow why the continue statement should be a break.. I'm constantly checking the stream for a new line. Process B is not constantly writing to the pipe stream so temp can and will be null. If I break then I will break out of the loop too soon.

Comment: If checking _Process.Responding is the wrong idea, then what is the correct way to tell if the process has become unresponsive and needs to be killed?

Comment: ReadLine only returns null when the stream ends. This happens exactly once and is the signal to exit the loop.; That depends on how you want to define unresponsive. Is Sleep(10000000) unresponsive to you? Why do you even want to detect some kind of unresponsiveness? There exists no general definition.

Comment: Process B hooks into a 3rd party API. It's possible (although unlikely) that the program might become unresponsive. I guess unresponsive would be nothing happening after a minute

Comment: Sounds like a 1 min execution timeout is a good idea, or a 1 min read timeout per line. As I said, Responding is GUI-based. Did you see that statement? Likely makes it unsuitable.